# Importing blender to Unity issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, export, blender, modeling

When I am exporting something from blender to Unity it is looks like this, How can I import without breaking it into parts?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KA8d3.png)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a model already decomposed it can be more complicated but if it's your object go to blender then merge all the elements before exporting.